# SSRS - How to show "No Data Found" Message to end user

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

How to show "**No Data Found**" Message to end user through **SSRS** without opening Report in Front end if **Procedure** is not returning any row.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand questions correctly, then

Add a text box with expression

```
=IIF(Count(<SomeId Field>,"DataSet1")=0,"No Data Returned", nothing)
```

and set the visibility of this textbox as

```
=IIF(Count(<SomeId Field>,"DataSet1")=0,False,True)
```

This should do the job

Comment: The visibility could be calculated without an IIF method: Count(<SomeID Field>, "DataSet1") = 0. Especially since the property is "Hidden" and should be true when the count is zero. Another alternative would be to set the "No Rows" property on the Tablix itself.

Comment: But if I do this stuff then still it is going to open the report before showing the result. But I did not want to open the report, if there is no data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can ref to this. There is a simple way to set no row message for a tablix on ssrs.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220407.aspx